# Timestamp calculated in Javascript and C# are different

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, timestamp

I am calculating `TimeStamp` in `javascript` using following code

`var timestamp = new Date;`

that gives me result `1436504446858` contain `13` digits depend upon current time.

The same thing calculated in `C#` using following code

```
DateTime centuryBegin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
long elapsedTicks = currentDate.Ticks - centuryBegin.Ticks;
```

Here i got result  `14365252465308044` that contains `17` digits

Why the two methods gives so much of difference ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why the two methods gives so much of difference ?

The Javascript code is giving you the number of *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch.

The .NET code (if you'd got it right - more on that in a second) is giving you the number of *ticks* since the Unix epoch. There are 10 million ticks per second, so 10,000 ticks per millisecond. That's why you're getting 4 more digits.

Now, the other problem is that your .NET code is using the *local* time - whereas it should reflect the *UTC* time, given that you're finding the number of ticks (or milliseconds) since the Unix epoch, which is midnight January 1st in 1970 *UTC*. So you want:

```
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeSpan elapsedTime = utcNow - unixEpoch;
double millis = elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Note how if you represent the difference in time as a `TimeSpan`, you can convert it to the units you're interested in. (Although a `TimeSpan` is just "a length of time" which doesn't know a start/end, so you can't use it to find a difference in variable-length units such as years and months.)